# Audit Entity Framework deleted entries preserving previous value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, audit

I've been struggling for a while with a problem that consists on auditing generically database entities when they're saved. I have a project that uses EF 6 and it was required to me to create a "non-invasive" method to audit entities when they're added, modified or deleted. I have to store a JSON of the inserted entity, modified entity or deleted entity without interfering with the normal flow. The project has a Database First implementation.

My solution was simple, add a partial class of any entity that the rest of the programmers want to audit implementing IAudit which is basically an empty interface to get all changes from entities that implement it.

```
public interface IAudit {}
```

I have a Currencies entity that just implement it without any other code (I could do something else in the future but I don't need it)

```
public partial class Currencies : IAudit
```

I override the SaveChanges method to look for entities to audit

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

    // This linq looks for new entities that were marked for audit
    CreateAuditLog(System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added);
    CreateAuditLog(System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified);
    CreateAuditLog(System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted);

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

The solution calls 3 times the CreateAuditLog because in the near future I need to implement a configuration to audit whatever the user decides, might be from a database configuration that is activated/deactivated by users.

Everything worked perfectly, I was able to get saved entities in the specified state:

```
    private void CreateAuditLog(System.Data.Entity.EntityState state)
    {
        var auditedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries<IAudit>()
            .Where(p => p.State == state)
            .Select(p => p.Entity);

       ... some code that do something else

       foreach (var auditedEntity in auditedEntities)
       {
          ... some information I required to add

         strJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(auditedEntity, new EFNavigationPropertyConverter());

          ... some code to save audit information

       }

    }
```

The problem is I lose every value in the Deleted state, I only get the ID, there's no information in the properties except the ID and there is no any possibility of extract it in any way. I looked for every single solution in StackOverflow and other websites and there is nothing to recover the original information.
How can I get the previous deleted values to store them in the same way I'm storing Added and Modified entities?

Comment: I've been working on a library that might help. Take a look at [Audit.EntityFramework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Audit.entityframework/) library, it intercepts SaveChanges() and can be configured to filter the entities you want to audit.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a couple of days to figure it out. Might be the solution is a bit complex but I tried several less complex options with not a good result.

First, as I'm just auditing Delete in a different way I separated Deleted state from Added and Modified that work well with no change. Deleted state is a particular case and I treat it like that.

First, I needed to obtain the original values from the database. In the Deleted state they're gone, there's not any possibility of recovering them from the entity. It's possible to obtain them with the following code:

```
var databaseValues = this.Entry(auditedEntity).GetDatabaseValues();
```

The result is just a collection of DB property values (DbPropertyValues). If I can get the original values I set the original values from the deleted entity:

```
dbEntityEntry.OriginalValues.SetValues(databaseValues);
```

This line just fills the entity original values, it doesn't modify the current value at all. It's useful to do it that way because it takes some code to check every property and set it ourselves, it's an interesting shortcut.
Now, the problem is I don't have the entity to serialize, so I need a new one which in my case I create by reflection because I don't know the type (I receive entities that implement IAudit)

```
Type type = auditedEntity.GetType();
var auditDeletedEntity = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

This is the entity I will serialize to store the audit later.

Now, the complex part, I need to get the entity properties and fill them by reflection from the original values set in the entity:

```
foreach (var propertyInfo in type.GetProperties())
{
    if (!propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsArray && !propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsGenericType)
    {
        var propertyValue = originalValues.GetValue<object>(propertyInfo.Name);
        auditDeletedEntity.GetType().InvokeMember(propertyInfo.Name,
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.SetProperty,
            Type.DefaultBinder, auditDeletedEntity, new[] { propertyValue });
    }
}
```

I had to check generic and array types to avoid following EF relations that are not going to work with this method and I also don't need (I need the object not the whole tree)

After that I simply need to serialize the audited deleted entity:

```
strJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(auditDeletedEntity, new EFNavigationPropertyConverter());
```

The code looks like this:

```
string strJSON = string.Empty;
if (state == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted)
{
    var databaseValues = this.Entry(auditedEntity).GetDatabaseValues();

    // Get original values from the database (the only option, in the delete method they're lost)
    DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = this.Entry(auditedEntity);
    if (databaseValues != null)
    {
        dbEntityEntry.OriginalValues.SetValues(databaseValues);
        var originalValues = this.Entry(auditedEntity).OriginalValues;
        Type type = auditedEntity.GetType();
        var auditDeletedEntity = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        // Get properties by reflection
        foreach (var propertyInfo in type.GetProperties())
        {
            if (!propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsArray && !propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsGenericType)
            {
                var propertyValue = originalValues.GetValue<object>(propertyInfo.Name);
                auditDeletedEntity.GetType().InvokeMember(propertyInfo.Name,
                    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.SetProperty,
                    Type.DefaultBinder, auditDeletedEntity, new[] { propertyValue });
            }
        }
        strJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(auditDeletedEntity, new EFNavigationPropertyConverter());
    }
}
else
{
    strJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(auditedEntity, new EFNavigationPropertyConverter());
}
```

Might be there's a better way but I seriously spent a good amount of time looking for options and I couldn't find anything better.
Any suggestion or optimization is appreciated.